# How do I initialize an array in an input class for jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, initialization

```
var i;  
$('a.add').click(function() { 
    $('<p><input type="text" class = "count[i]" value="Enter Item Name"/></p>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('#selection');
    itemNumber ++;
});
```

What I want to do is to initialize an array called count in the input class and have i as a counter. I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about this.

Comment: I'mm not sure what you want, can you tell me what is the actual requirement? the class `count[i]` does not make any sense. When the add button is clicked you need to add a new input control and the class should be assigned as count1, count2 count3.. etc. Is it your requirement?

Comment: I think you may want to change `class` to `name` to start with, then you can reference it by `$_POST["name-in-quotes"]` or `$_GET["name-in-quotes"]` (PHP - or `Request("name-in-quotes")` / `Request.QueryString("name-in-quotes")` in VB.Net). You would want to set the name to something like `item-i`, where i is a number (specifically the number of inputs of type text which are there). You could then loop from 0 up, getting the value of each one as above until no value is returned. This is how I would do it. If you want a further explanation of this then please say so and I will add an answer.

Comment: @Arun: I should think, whatever the requirements, that harrison could change the requirements to suit my solution (above). This way a single class could be applied to each input, taking away the need to have a class for `item` and the number of the item (i.e. `.item1`, `.item2`, `.item3` etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MGEdQ/) and let me know whether this is what you want.
In this case we have a array of class names and when a new item is added the class name is obtained from the array using counter `i`.

Here is my script

```
var i = 0;  

var count = ["class-1", "class-2", "class-3", "class-4"]

$('a.add').click(function(e) { 
    var className = i < count.length ? count[i] : "count";

    $('<p><input type="text" class = "'+ className  +'" value="Enter Item Name"/></p>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('#selection');

    i++;
});
```

To access the `count[i]th` element you can use

```
$("#selection input." + count[i])
```

Or 
You can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MGEdQ/2/)
In this the class names are incremented using the counter `i` whenever a new item is added.

Script

```
var i = 0;  

$('a.add').click(function(e) { 
    $('<p><input type="text" class = "class-'+ (++i)  +'" value="Enter Item Name"/></p>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('#selection');
});
```

To access `count[i]th` element you can use

```
$("#selection input.class-" + i)
```

Comment: so, to access a specific one, it would be i =4, .class-i or something like that? to access class-4?

Comment: `class-` is just a notation i used. you can replace it with anything, say `item`. then the class names will be `item1`, `item2`,... etc.

Comment: alright, so how would i print out the value of class-4? thanks for the help by the way! it's really helping me out!

Comment: Which method are you using 1st or 2nd? If you are using the 1st method you can use `$("#selection input." + count[i]).val()` to get the value of the `i` th element. In the second method you can use `$("#selection input.class-" + i).val()` to get the value of `i`th element.

Comment: You can use `$("#selection input.class-" + i).val()` in that case.

Comment: lets say i want to know the 4th element, would i just say i = 4, then $("#selection input.class-" + i).val()?

Comment: yes, if you want to hard code then you can use `$("#selection input.class-4").val()` else you want to dynamically use it then you can use `$("#selection input.class-" + myvar).val()` where `myvar` is a variable which holds the count value if want.

Comment: wow! thanks! i finally got this to work! it's still a bit buggy but i'm going to start polishing it up! cheers! happy new year!

Comment: i actually have another question, im wondering if i should ask in this comment or start a new question? its fairly long. i was wondering if you can help again?

Comment: i started a new thread titled "Input does not show value of first element, but shows for the rest of the elements for jquery" since you started helping me, i'm sure it'll be easier for you than others to pick up ;) thanks in advance!

Comment: actually, nevermind, i found the bug and the misuse of an array, thanks ;)